# Is there any way to use Manipulate for eigenvectors calculation and their square plot

Tags: plotting, manipulate, linear-algebra, code-request

I have a matrix $H_{n\times n}$ . Now My job is to diagonalize it, we have $V1_{n\times n}$(set of eigenvectors of $H$). But my $H_{n\times n}$ is in terms of some parameters or variables(e.g. $t1$ and $t2$).I will fix one $t2 = 1$, will change $t1$. For example $t1$ goes from $0 \rightarrow10$. But I don't want to write all the values for $t1$ everytime. As we have [Manipulate](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) in Mathematica which does the job.

I have $H_{n\times n}(t1,t2)$ and then I am getting eigenvectors set (row wise) $V1_{n\times n}(t1=0\rightarrow10,t2=1)$, any value between $0$ and $10$ for $t1$. Then Matrix Plot of the $V=V1_{n\times n}(t1=t_{0},t2=1)*V1_{n\times n}(t1=t_{0},t2=1)$.

```
V1 = Eigenvectors[H /. {t1 -> 0.1, t2 -> 1}];
V = V1*V1;
MatrixPlot[V]
```

Is there a way so that I can use Manipulate for this Matrix plot for different set of $t1$ values. And I need not have to write this command for each values of $t1$.

*Note*: For a particular t1.[image: V Plot] For $t1 -> 10.0$, $t2 -> 1$. This is the Plot of V(n=20).

Comment: Anybody has any answer to this weird problem in Mathematica.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say your `H` is dependent on two parameters, `t1` and `t2`, and that you can fix one of them, say, `t2`. Hence `H` will be a function of `t1`, which I will denote with `t` in what follows (for illustrative purposes).

Having said that, let's define `H[t]` to be an explicit function of `t`. I'll take some random matrix for illustration:

```
n = 3;
H[t_] := RandomInteger[{0, 9}, {n, n}] + RandomChoice[{0, 1}, {n, n}] t;
MatrixForm@H[t]
```

[image]

and enclose `Eigenvectors` and `MatrixPlot` in a `Module`:

```
mp[t_] := Module[{V1, V},
  V1 = Chop@Eigenvectors[H[t]];
  V = V1*V1;
  MatrixPlot[V, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
  ]
```

which one can `Manipulate` straightforward:

```
Manipulate[mp[t], {t, 0, 10, 1.}]
```

[image]

---

One can of course make the matrix `H` be a function of two or more variables, e.g. `H[t1,t2,...]` (with an according change of `mp` into `mp[t1,t2,...]`), and add additional controls to `Manipulate`, which will just have more sliders, for each of the variables:

```
Ndim = 10;

H1[t1_] := {{0, t1}, {t1, 0}};
H2[t2_] := N@{{0, 0}, {t2, 0}};

H[t1_, t2_] := 
  ArrayFlatten@
   Table[H1[t1] KroneckerDelta[m, p1] + 
     H2[t2] KroneckerDelta[m + 1, p1] + 
     Transpose@H2[t2] KroneckerDelta[m - 1, p1], {m, 1, Ndim}, {p1, 1,
      Ndim}];

mp[t1_, t2_] := Module[{V1, V}, V1 = Chop@Eigenvectors[H[t1, t2]];
  V = V1*V1;
  MatrixPlot[V, PlotLegends -> Automatic]]

Manipulate[mp[t1, t2], {t1, 0, 10, 1.}, {t2, 0, 10, 1.}]
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. I ran it and got this. See this [Code Output](http://imgur.com/BJxvTUu)

Comment: Go with: `H1[t_] := {{0, t}, {t, 0}};`, `H[t_] := ArrayFlatten...` and remember to change `H1` into `H1[t]` in def of `H[t]`. Everything is a function but you didn't take that into account.

Comment: V=V1*V1 not V1.V1.

Comment: I ran the code, but this came: Set::write: Tag List in {{0,t},{t,0}}[t_] is Protected. **and** Set::write: Tag List in {{0,t,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{t,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,1,0,t,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,t,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1,0,t,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,t,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,t,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,t,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,t,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,t,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,t,0}}[t_] is Protected.

Comment: Because you already have `H1` etc defined; you need to clear the definitions; also, you might need to go with real numbers, i.e. `H2 = N@{{0, 0}, {1, 0}};` is sufficient. Your matrix gives interesting plots :)

Comment: I didn't get this, you said _clear the definitions_. How that can be done?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46115/discussion-between-l-k-and-corey979).

Comment: Please do not remove `N@` from the code, this causes the code to malfunction.

Comment: @Feyre Thanks for this I think thats why my code is not working. But why we put it on `H2[t2_]` not `H1[t1_]`.

Answer (score 4):

corey979's answer is good, and I have used the code to create the matrix from his answer. You can also stay closer to your initial version (using replace rather than a function call):

```
n = 5;
h = RandomInteger[{0, 9}, {n, n}] + RandomChoice[{0, 1}, {n, n}] t;
Manipulate[v = Eigenvectors[h /. t -> tval]; MatrixPlot[v*v], {tval, 0, 10}]
```

For the exact form of H you define in the comment below, the code would be:

```
Ndim = 10; H1[t_] := {{0, t}, {t, 0}}; H2 = N@{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}; 
H[t_] := ArrayFlatten@
  Table[H1[t] KroneckerDelta[m, p1] + H2 KroneckerDelta[m + 1, p1] + 
    Transpose[H2] KroneckerDelta[m - 1, p1], {m, 1, Ndim}, {p1, 1, Ndim}];
Manipulate[v = Eigenvectors[H[t] /. t -> tval]; MatrixPlot[v*v], {tval, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: I want to plot v*v as a function of t.

Comment: After running this I got [Output](http://imgur.com/vZWKDoh)

Comment: L.K. The code in your output file is not the same as I proposed above. Remove the MatrixForm from H.

Comment: THis is the output I got [New Output](http://imgur.com/a/8Jtxz)

Comment: I removed the : from H definition, then also same output

Comment: You are defining your H incorrectly. Please paste your code (not an image of your code) in your problem statement.

Comment: `Ndim = 10;
H1[t] = {{0, t}, {t, 0}};
H2 = N@{{0, 0}, {1, 0}};
H[t] = ArrayFlatten@
   Table[H1 KroneckerDelta[m, p1] + H2 KroneckerDelta[m + 1, p1] + 
     Transpose[H2] KroneckerDelta[m - 1, p1], {m, 1, Ndim}, {p1, 1, 
     Ndim}];
Manipulate[v = Eigenvectors[H /. t -> tval]; 
 MatrixPlot[v*v], {tval, 0, 10}]`

Comment: This is precisely my code'

Comment: see update using your function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46130/discussion-between-l-k-and-bill-s).